# $http code firing at different times, how to fire in order

Tags: angularjs

My knowledge of angular is extremely limited. EDIT: I am using $http.jsonp() to pull data from within an if statment

```
.controller('MagazineCtrl', function ($scope, $stuff ... )
    $scope.vars

    console.log('before if statement');

    if ($rootScope.attr === undefined )
    {
         $http.jsonp( url ).then{
               console.log('if statement');
         }
    }

    console.log('after if statement');
```

My output is

```
before if statement
after if statement
if statement
```

How can I get the code to run in the correct order? Is there a time-out function or something? I think a 'promise' may be what I'm looking for but I don't know if the code will still fire in order. How can I wait for the $http request to complete and complete the if statement before continuing?

Comment: Please add reproducible version to Plunker, so we can see all your code.

Comment: There is a timeout function - `$timeout(function(){...},[#milliseconds]);` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: `$timeout` shouldn't be needed here, as this code is not async.

Comment: Apologies. I have heavily edited the code. I missed a very critical point about $http

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that `$timeout` should be used, i was just answering the user's question on whether or not there is a "time-out function or something?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `$http.jsonp` is async, which means the code will not block waiting for a response.

You should read your code like this:

```
.controller('MagazineCtrl', function ($scope, $stuff ... )
    console.log('before');

    if ($rootScope.attr === undefined ) {
       $http.jsonp( url ).then( function() {
         console.log('after');
       });
    }
```

If you need the result of the `$http.jsonp` call, then place the "after" code inside the `then` callback.

More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
.controller('MagazineCtrl', function ($scope, $stuff ... ) {
    console.log('before if statement');

    function runAfter() {
        console.log('after if statement');
    }

    if ($rootScope.attr === undefined ) {
        $http.jsonp(url).then(function() {
            console.log('if statement');
            runAfter();
        });
    }
    else {
        runAfter();
    }
}
```

This way "after if" will always be run after the "if statement" but still run if $rootScope.attr is defined.